# gThumb for file browsing

Tags: 11.10

Ubuntu 11.10 enforces gThumb for even normal non-image file browsing. gthumb might be a good image browser but its a pathetic file browser (compared to nautilus) can we get nautilus back in 11.10 ?

Comment: Nautilus is the default file browser in 11.10. Really don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: Can you add more detail? gthumb isn't included by default in ubuntu, did you perhaps install it and now it's accidentally opening things?

Comment: Hmm...I did install gThumb before upgrading 11.04 to 11.10. I am not sure how gthumb became the default file browser after the upgrade. Perhaps, the upgrade to 11.10 was too messy. Will format the drive(sigh) and check again.

Answer (score 2):

I have just found a solution here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager#Restoring_Nautilus_as_a_default

Go to the end of the article and you will find the easiest way to do it as follows:

---

```
One more way - for "mousemonkeys", like me

Just do in terminal

exo-preferred-applications

then switch to Utilities tab and select File Manager you prefer. And that's all!
```

---

You could need to install exo-utils before, but it will prompt you if necessary.
Anyway the command to install it is:

```
sudo apt-get install exo-utils
```